# How to split a huge .CSV file into n smaller files when an index in a particular column changes?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, file, awk

I have been given five huge .CSV files that contain columns of data.  The files are so large that they don't even load completely in EXCEL.  I can load them if I open them in a text editor, however.

I want to split each file into n smaller files according to an index in the first column.  For example, each file contains data for 50 locations.  Location 1 is called JEANNE in the first column.  So there are an arbitrary number (let's say "m") of rows of data for JEANNE.  At row m+1, JEANNE changes to ALICE (for example) and there are l rows of data for ALICE, and so on for all the other sites.

Does anyone know how I can do this in something like Awk without having to know the number of rows of data for each site in advance, but by using the change in index (e.g., JEANNE to ALICE)?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you want to split such that each unique location occupies its own file?  i.e. jeanne.csv contains all the rows that had column 1 == jeanne, alice.csv contains all rows that had column 1 == alice, etc?

Comment: @biomiker, sorry I wasn't clear.  Yes, I want all of the "JEANNE" rows to go into their own file called "JEANNE" and all of the "ALICE" rows to go into their own file called "ALICE," and so on.  A complicating issue is that I have five massive files and all of them have different numbers of columns and location (e.g., JEANNE) rows.  I hope I have been clear, but if not, please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Something like this might get you started: `awk '{ print $0 >> $1 }' csv_file.txt`

Comment: @andirc, thank you for that suggestion.  Sorry--which part specifies that the "JEANNE" rows (for example) have to be moved?  I have very little experience with Awk.  I'm on the road but will try it as soon as I can, hopefully tonight but maybe first thing tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be sufficient to split the csv file into smaller files each grouped by the first column in the csv:

```
awk -F, '{ print >> ($1".part.csv") }' file.csv
```

Breakdown

```
# awk iterates over each line in the specified input file
awk -F,                   # tell awk to split the lin into columns on ","
    '{ print              # print whole line
       >>                 # append to file
       ($1".part.csv") }' # output file is first columns prefixed with ".part.csv" 
     file.csv             # input file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `cut` that column, pipe to `sort -u`, and iterate over those lines to grep into separate files.

Comment:  That's funny. It's like when I take my car in to be fixed and the mechanic says *"Oh you can do it yourself, just whip the cylinder head and block off, pop in a new set of piston rings and re-grind the valve seats while you're there and it'll all be fine."*

Comment: If you're both mechanics, then yeah! And we're all mechanics here. ^_^ Some of us are just used to lawmowers, others are used to fighter jets, and also a bunch of auto mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work?

NOTE:  This assumes comma separated values per "CSV".  Of course, use the appropriate delimiter for your data.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$@

locs=`cut -d, -f1 $files | sort -u`

for loc in $locs
do
    grep -h "^${loc}," $files > ${loc}.csv
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.  Unfortunately, I have had to leave the house for the evening, but will try it as soon as I get back, either tonight or tomorrow morning.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @andlrc's answer is better!  Go with that.

Comment: thank you, that's very humble of you!  I appreciate them both and am looking forward to trying them both once I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `python3`:

```
delimiter = ","
filename = "file.csv"
filehandles = {}
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        first_col = line.split(delimiter, 1)[0]
        subfilename = first_col + "_" + filename
        if subfilename not in filehandles.keys():
            filehandles[subfilename] = open(first_col, "w")
        filehandles[subfilename].write(line)
for fh in filehandles.values():
    fh.close()
```

I assuemd `,` is used as separator and `file.csv` is your filename. Explanation: I am opening file and iterate over lines (`for line in f`) so I do not load whole file to memory, but one line at a time. Then I split line once and get first value (`[0]` as python indices are 0-based), I create name of part file by concating column value, "_" and original filename. If it is first occurence I open filehandle and add it to dictionary with filehandles. Then I write current line to appropiate file. After all writing is done I `.close()` all handles for part files. Note I do not do this for main file handle as it used in `with`.